# Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found after Android Studio and Gradle updates

Tags: linux, debian, android, android-studio

I have recently updated Android Studio and Gradle. Now when I open my project, I receive the gradle sync error: **Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found**.

I can't check my gradle version with `./gradlew -v` because it says that I have no JAVA_HOME, no PATH and no java command. But everything was OK before I updated gradle and Android studio.

So, the question is what have I do to continue using Android stdio?

Comment: Seems to be related to an incompatible Gradle version, I have not found anymore details beyond that.